# Login en klotin no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, mysql, json, kotlin, android-volley

Estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión para mi aplicación en android studio utilizando kotlin. El caso es que aunque pongas un usurario y la contraseña correspondiente que se encuentra en mysql pone que es incorrecto. El logcat no me da ningún error, y en el evenlog tampoco, por lo creo que el fallo está en que hay un if en el que si el response no está vacío o es igual a true te deja pasar a la otra pantalla, y si no te dice que el usuario o la contraseña son incorrectas. Creo que el código está mal en la parte de php del json y en el if de klotin, pero no se como solucionarlo. ¿Qué debería modificar de mi código? No se como arreglar el problema y agradezco cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias.
Este es el código php:

```
<?php
  require 'database.php';
if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre');
    $records->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $message ='';
    if (count($results)>0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])){
        $success = True;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      }else {
        $success = False;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      }
};
?>
```

Y este es el codigo de android studio (kotlin):

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import java.util.HashMap

class Login : AppCompatActivity() {
    var nombreusuariologin: EditText? = null
    var contraseñalogin: EditText? = null
    var enviarlogin: Button? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        nombreusuariologin = findViewById(R.id.nombreusuario)
        contraseñalogin = findViewById(R.id.contraseña)
        enviarlogin = findViewById(R.id.enviarlogin)
        enviarlogin!!.setOnClickListener { validarUsuario("http://192.168.1.47/Registro/loginapp.php") }
    }
    private fun validarUsuario(URL: String) {
        val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST,
            URL,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                if(response != null && response == "true"){
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@Login,
                        "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            },
           Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@Login,
                    error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val parametros: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                parametros.put("nombre",nombreusuariologin?.text.toString())
                parametros.put("password",contraseñalogin?.text.toString())
                return parametros
            }
        }
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo primero que veo es que mandas un `StringRequest` pero desde PHP mandas un `JSON`. Entonces, o mandas un `JSONObjectRequest`  desde Android y dejas el código PHP como está (yo haría eso), o mandas desde PHP una cadena, no un JSON.

Comment: Si quieres, para depurar más rápido, puedes hacer esto desde PHP: comentar estas dos líneas: `$success = True;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` y poner esto: `echo "true";`  y comentar estas dos líneas: `$success = False;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` cambiándolo por `echo "false";` Ya cuando funcione, es mejor implementar un JSON por varios motivos. El problema es que tu código **no es coherente**. En Android tú verificas así: `if(response != null && response == "true"){` pero ...

Comment: desde el servidor **nunca mandas una cadena con el valor "true"** y además, como ya dije, **mandas un JSON, habiendo declarado un `StringRequest`**. Pues eso, **incoherencia** entre una parte y otra.

Comment: @A.Cedano Agradezco muchísimo tu respuesta, ahora ya sé cual es el error. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.